# Can i install ubuntu on my new alienware r7 laptop WITH all driver support (for rtx 3070ti, i7 12700h, wifi card)?

Tags: drivers

I just bought a new alienware r7. I've been using Ubuntu since 2018. So, will any problems arise regarding gpu drivers and wifi card or will it bottleneck than windows 11. Because it performed pretty good on my previous laptop. Do I need to update the linux kernel and stuff? Also, the version I'm planning to install is ubuntu 22.04. Please respond ASAP

Comment: No one can guess what issues you may or may not have. Install it. If you have issues come back here and ask for some assistance. This statement from your question is confusing " or will it bottleneck than windows 11. ". A good start is to follow an official install guide https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Typically, linux works on Alienware systems.  However, for all the ones I've looked at, it is not supported, and you can't get warranty support if linux is installed.  I've found that alienware systems are unstable with linux installed.  (So keep windows in dual boot so you can get warranty support and do firmware updates.) This doesn't mean it doesn't work, but it does mean they have strange crashes, hangs, and sometimes don't wake up from sleep.  (So disable sleep...)  I would not buy an Alienware system to put linux on it unless it came that way.  But if you've already bought it, go for it.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try and [create an Ubuntu bootable USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#3-create-a-bootable-usb-stick), then boot it and click Try Ubuntu, then attempt to use it for a while. Any changes you make wouldn't be saved, but if everything functions properly, you should be set.

Also, if you plan on using the laptop in question for gaming, give [Pop!_OS](https://pop.system76.com/) a try - it's a bit nicer for games than vanilla Ubuntu.